# Problems with Arrays and Linker

Tags: c++, arrays, function, linker, fatal-error

I typed the following code into Microsoft Visual C++ to compute and display gas mileage.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
//Christopher Hernandez, Programmer
//global variables
int day [3]; 
int mil [3];
int gal [3];
int mpg [3];
//function prototype
void CalcAverage (int arr1[], int arr2[], int size);
//main program
int main()
{
//local variables
char month [7];

cout << "Please enter the starting month" << endl;
cin >> month;

cout << "Please enter starting day entry 1" << endl;
cin >> day [0];
cout << "entry 2" << endl;
cin >> day [2];
cout << "entry 3" << endl;
cin >> day [3];
cout << "entry 4" << endl;
cin>> day [4];

cout << "Please enter gallons entry 1" << endl;
cin >> gal [0];
cout << "entry 2" << endl;
cin >> gal [1];
cout << "entry 3" << endl;
cin >> gal [2];
cout << "entry 4" << endl;
cin >> gal [3];

cout << "Please enter miles entry 1" << endl;
cin >> mil [0];
cout << "entry 2" << endl;
cin >> mil [1];
cout << "entry 3" << endl;
cin >> mil [2];
cout << "entry 4" << endl;
cin >> mil [3];

CalcAverage (gal,mil,3);

cout << "Week of" << "\tGallons" << "\tMiles" << "\tMPG" << endl;
cout << "_ _ _ _ _ _ _" << "\t_ _ _ _ _" << "\t_ _ _ _"  << endl;
cout << month [0] <<  " " << day [0] << "\t" << gal [0] << "\t" << mil [0] << "\t" << mpg [0] <<     endl;
cout << month [1] <<  " " << day [1] << "\t" << gal [1] << "\t" << mil [1] << "\t" << mpg [1] <<     endl;
cout << month [2] <<  " " << day [2] << "\t" << gal [2] << "\t" << mil [2] << "\t" << mpg [2] <<     endl;
cout << month [3] <<  " " << day [3] << "\t" << gal [3] << "\t" << mil [3] << "\t" << mpg [3] <<     endl;

system("PAUSE");

}
//function definition
void CalcAverage (int g, int m, int size)
{
//statements
mpg [0] = mil [0] / gal [0];
mpg [1] = mil [1] / gal [1];
mpg [2] = mil [2] / gal [2];
mpg [3] = mil [3] / gal [3];

}
```

Needless to say I did not get the desired output.  Instead I recieved the following errors

```
1>c:\users\computer\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\gasmileage\gasmileage\gasmileage.cpp    (66): warning C4789: destination of memory copy is too small

1>gasmileage.obj : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/INCREMENTAL:NO' specification

1>gasmileage.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl CalcAverage(int * const,int * const,int)" (?CalcAverage@@YAXQAH0H@Z) referenced in function _main

1>C:\Users\COMPUTER\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\GasMileage\Debug\GasMileage.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

What is the problem with my code? Why am I getting these errors?

*I should also note that I have incremental linking set to "off", because when I have it on I am unable to run programs without getting a message that my Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 is out of date (this message also forces me to abort the program)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your function prototype is:

```
void CalcAverage (int arr1[], int arr2[], int size);
```

But the actual function definition is:

```
void CalcAverage (int g, int m, int size)
```